# How can I answer ESTA question when I don't have all the required details?

Tags: passports, esta, dual-nationality

The [ESTA application](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e2s1) form asks

> Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?

[image]

How should I fill out the application form if I am no longer in physical possession of an expired passport from another country?

Comment: This is fully answered by the help available on the form itself. Anyone looking for the answer to this question should use that help, not the answers posted here, which may be out of date or unintentionally inaccurate.

Answer (score 88):

Move your mouse over the circled `?` just above the drop-down. It'll tell you:

[image]

> If you have been issued one of these documents from another country, but you do not remember the passport number or national identification card number and the year of expiration answer "UNKNOWN" in the passport number field and four zeros "0000" in the year of expiration field.

Comment: I've deleted my answer in favour of this one because even though they both say the same thing, this one is better and provides exactly what the OP is looking for

Comment: @HankyPanky I wish I could upvote you 5x for that, but I can't even upvote you once! Oh wait. *You have other answers.*

Comment: @Harper: Please don't. Answers should be evaluated on an individual basis, not on the basis of the individual who posted them.

Comment: @Harper - Not only that, but you'll be caught by the system and your votes reversed if you target an _individual_ for voting.

Comment: @MatthieuM I'm aware, they were answers I had recalled seeing before and thought were worthy of upvotes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! 
Being pedantic, do you list all your childhood passports - how many should an applicant list?

Comment: @Giramondo the ESTA site gives inconsistent info. The help bubble for the expiration states "If you have multiple passports or national identity cards for each country please list all current and expired documents for each country that issued you a document.", while the help page states "If you have any additional passports, please enter the most recent passport information, even if that passport is expired". The answers are not completely consistent with the current form either. I would personally go for the latest passport, and possibly list any previous ones I still have the details for.